$f : I \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable at $x_0 \in I$ but $f^{-1}$ discontinuous at $f(x_0)$
I need to find a function $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$, where $I$ is an interval (can be open, closed, bounded or unbounded - it doesn't matter), so that $f: I \to f(I)$ is bijective, $f$ is differentiable at $x_0 \in I$, $f'(x_0) \neq 0$, but $f^{-1}$ is discontinuous at $f(x_0)$.
I didn't manage to find such an example, but I know that $f$ must have points of discontinues in every neighborhood of $x_0$, otherwise it won't work.

Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you very much!
